# Sort by Alphabets, Numbers, Special character order

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
    SELECT * FROM details
    ORDER BY cast(SUBSTRING(name,'^[a-zA-Z]+') as varchar) orderDirection NULLS LAST,
    cast(SUBSTRING(name,'^\d+') as numeric) orderDirection NULLS LAST, name orderDirection;
```

This query retrieves data in ASC or DESC depends on the input we gave for 'orderDirection',
But the problem is Capital letters and small letters also will be treated as separate sort.
So help me in finding proper query with adding something in this query itself(Because I am using some generic codes for creating this)

**Current Result:**

```
"Came"

"Result"

"Result came"

"came"

"result"

"01 Result"

"# Result"
```

**Expected Result:**

```
"Came"

"came"

"Result"

"result"

"Result came"

"01 Result"

"# Result"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert the strings to lowercase before ordering you will get the results you want:

```
SELECT * FROM details
ORDER BY cast(SUBSTRING(LOWER(name,'^[a-z]+')) as varchar) DESC NULLS LAST,
         cast(SUBSTRING(name,'^\d+') as numeric) DESC NULLS LAST,
         LOWER(name) DESC;
```

Comment: ORDER BY cast(SUBSTRING(LOWER(name),'^[a-z]+') as varchar) DESC NULLS LAST
Please change like this, Since your query got some error, But rephrased like above it worked, Thank you very much

Comment: @codeSeeker I've updated as you suggested. I'm glad the query worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Get a recent PostgreSQL version that is built with a recent ICU library and create your own collation:

```
CREATE COLLATION english_weird (
   PROVIDER = 'icu',
   LOCALE = 'en-u-kr-punct-symbol-currency-digit-latn'
);
```

Then use it for sorting:

```
ORDER BY name COLLATE english_weird DESC
```

If you always want that order for that column, define it accordingly:

```
ALTER TABLE details
   ALTER name TYPE text COLLATE english_weird;
```

Comment: While giving desc, Alphabets should desc first, Numbers should be in desc second, then Special chars should be in desc. That we cant achieve  with this right. Anyway thanks for the valuable info

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "desc" here, but other than that that's exactly what that collation does, right? Perhaps I misunderstood, your question was not totally clear to me.

Comment: Yes, Of course, Yours is perfectly working when I need Ascending order, But when I need Descending order its little different here, I don't need reverse of ascending, thats what happening in this.

Comment: Ah, I get you. Sometimes you have `DESC`, sometimes not.